# Когда "бронзовый" знак станет "серебряным"?

Tags: поддержка, метки, знаки

Похожих вопросов, вроде бы, много, но конкретного ответа не нашёл. Если же проморгал где-то, ткните носом :)
В условии получения бронзового знака сказано: "Заработать не менее 100 баллов рейтинга за минимум 20 ответов", при этом, как я понимаю, должно быть задано вопросов с данным тегом не менее сотни. А вот для серебряного сколько вопросов должно быть задано?
Смотрим  [тег "windows", количество вопросов - 2292](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows). Но он до сих пор "ходит в бронзовых". Сколько вопросов нужно, чтобы он стал серебряным? Или серебряным он станет только тогда, когда кто-то наберет минимальные требования (400 баллов рейтинга; 80 ответов по метке)? Или же, вообще, требует действие руками, чтобы знак мог стать серебряным?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Знаки по меткам даются **участникам**, которые успешно отвечали на вопросы с соответствующими метками. И вот когда кол-во ответов **конкретного участника** и их суммарный рейтинг превышают определенный порог, участник получает соответствующий знак: бронзовый, серебряный, золотой. Общее количество вопросов на сайте не имеет значения для получения знака, но их [должно быть не меньше 100](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311957/4928642).

Comment: То есть, фактически, на данный момент просто нет ни одного участника, у которого по метке 'windows' было бы "400 баллов рейтинга; 80 ответов по метке"?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov именно. Список лучших участников по метке доступен на странице метки [tag:windows]. [Прямая ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/windows/topusers).

Comment: Вообще-то у знаков по меткам есть минимальное число вопросов, которое по этим меткам должно быть на сайте.

Comment: @Qwertiy инфа сотка?

Comment: @alexolut, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311957/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Количество вопросов не имеет значения для того, получил ли ты знак по метке или нет.

Надо только писать хорошие ответы на вопросы, и все.

Для бронзового надо 100 баллов на 20 ответов, для серебряного - 400 на 80, и наконец, для золотого - 1000 на 200.

Так что вопросы не имеют никакого значения в знаках за метки.